# Using JAXB episode files with wsimport

Tags: jaxb, xsd, wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport

There are two WSDLs which share some of schemas they use to define their datatypes. Here is an example of one of the WSDLs:

```
<wsdl:definitions
    name="FooService"
    targetNamespace="http://xmlns.my.org/services/FooService/v001"
    xmlns:srv="http://xmlns.my.org/services/FooService/v001"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fault="java:org.my.exception"
    ...
>
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="java:org.my.exception" schemaLocation="../xsd/common/BusinessException.xsd"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://xmlns.my.org/services/FooServiceMessages/v001" schemaLocation="../xsd/fooservice/FooServiceMessages_v001.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    ...
    <wsdl:message name="BusinessException">
        <wsdl:part element="fault:BusinessException" name="BusinessException"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    ...
    <wsdl:portType name="IFooService">
        <wsdl:operation name="getItems">
            ...
            <wsdl:fault message="srv:BusinessException" name="BusinessException"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        ...
    </wsdl:portType>
    ...
</wsdl:definitions>
```

`BusinessException.xsd` is one of the common schemes.

I'm trying to generate Java code by these WSDLs with `wsimport`. It would be reasonable to compile common schemas separately from WSDLd and then reuse classes derived from these schemas while compiling WSDLs. For this purpose I've generated a JAXB episode file along with common Java code:

```
<bindings version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="java:org.my.exception">
    <schemaBindings map="false">
      <package name="org.my.integration.dto.common"/>
    </schemaBindings>
    <bindings scd="~tns:BusinessException">
      <class ref="org.my.integration.dto.common.BusinessException"/>
    </bindings>
  </bindings>
  <bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.my.org/BaseIdentifiers/v001">
    <schemaBindings map="false">
      <package name="org.my.integration.dto.common"/>
    </schemaBindings>
    <bindings scd="~tns:EntityIdentifierListType">
      <class ref="org.my.integration.dto.common.EntityIdentifierListType"/>
    </bindings>
    <bindings scd="~tns:...">
      <class ref="..."/>
    </bindings>
    ...
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

`http://xmlns.my.org/BaseIdentifiers/v001` namespace is filled with another common schema that's imported in `FooServiceMessages_v001.xsd` (actually in a schema that's imported in a schema that's ... that's imported in `FooServiceMessages_v001.xsd`).

Here is a wsimport call which I use to generate Java code:

```
wsimport -B-XautoNameResolution -Xnocompile -s ./../java/ -verbose -b ./bindings/fooservice/jaxws-bindings.xml -b ./bindings/fooservice/jaxb-bindings.xml -b ./bindings/common/common.episode -keep ./wsdl/FooService_v001.wsdl
```

The following error occurs on this call:

```
[ERROR] Schema descriptor {java:org.my.exception}BusinessException in message part "BusinessException" is not defined and could not be bound to Java. ...
```

BTW if a binding for `BusinessException.xsd` is described in a plain external JAXB binding file (not in a episode file) all works fine. Looks like `wsimport` has some problems with handling episode files which describe bindings for schemes which are imported in WSDL directly.

Is there a way to use episode files with `wsimport` for schemes directly imported in WSDL (like `BusinessException.xsd` in my case)?

Answer (score 1):

As https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/514 says it is impossible to generate sources for WSDL using JAXB episodes.

Sun/Oracle engineers unable to implement necessary enhancement for 11 years (2008-2019). And recently Oracle thrown sources to Eclipse project (October 2018).

I generate WSDL binding without episodes, as final step I remove packages from common schema. For Gradle it looks like:

```
wsimport {
    wsdl = file("${project.rootDir}/wsdl/PingService.wsdl")
    bindings = files(...)
}
task('afterWsimport', type: Delete) {
    delete new File(file(wsimport.javaDir), "com/bla/schema")
    delete new File(file(wsimport.javaDir), "com/foo")
}
wsimport.finalizedBy(afterWsimport)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is some kind of bug or incorrect behavior of wsimport. wsdl2java tool from Apache CXF lacks this problem.

Comment: See [JAXB-514](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-514) and [JAX_WS-368](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-368)